# $G_n/A_n$ Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have seen a question like this but not quite the same, [Convergence of geometric mean over arithmetic mean $G_n / A_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154903/convergence-of-geometric-mean-over-arithmetic-mean-g-n-a-n). 
and this [$a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d$, $b_n=\frac{\sqrt[n]{a_1 \cdot a_2 ... \cdot a_n}}{\frac{a_1+a_2...+ a_n}{n}}$ Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n$ exists, and find it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481214/a-n-a-1-n-1d-b-n-frac-sqrtna-1-cdot-a-2-cdot-a-n-fraca) in which the answer included finding the limit. 
given an arithmetic sequence $a_n$ with $a_1\gt0$ and a difference $d\gt0$ prove that the sequence: $$B_n=\frac{G_n}{A_n}$$ where $G_n = \sqrt[n]{a_1 \dots \cdot a_n}$ and $A_n = \frac{a_1+ \cdot +a_n}n,$
converges.

All I've done so far:
$$0\le B_n\le1$$ So for example showing that $B_n$ is decreasing will suffice.
I also managed to get that $B_n\rightarrow \frac{2}e$ through a not-so-formal proof. 
given that in the question we were asked to prove the convergence and then calculate the limit, I want to see how it's done without calculating the limit (or knowing it beforehand).

Comment: You seem to be unhappy with the assumption $a_1,d > 0$.  Later you recite those assumptions in your work.  You do not clearly state the problem (separated from your brief survey of prior work and from your work so far), so it is unclear whether that condition is required.  Note that the geometric mean may fail to be defined if $d < 0$, depending on whether $\lfloor a_1/d\rfloor$ is odd or even.

Comment: @EricTowers I couldn't prove it for $a_1,d\lt0$, Of course, a proof for $a_1,d\gt0$ would be very appreciated. also, it wasn't mentioned in the question I was given but you can assume the GM is defined.

Comment: I also just realized that if you assume that the GM is defined you can prove it for an $N$ such that for every $n\ge N : a_n\le0$ and then it's the same as the positive proof.

Comment: I note that if one of the $a_i = 0$, then $B_n \rightarrow 0$.  If all the $a_i = 1$, then $B_n = 1$ for all $n$.  I'm very skeptical of your $2/\mathrm{e}$ estimate.  Are you able to say anything about $\left| \left( \frac{B_{n+1}}{B_n} \right)^{n(n+1)}\right|$, perhaps using a vast simplification of $A_n$ since you can evaluate that sum?

Comment: you're right about the $a_i$=0 but see that i changed the question to only include $a_1,d\gt0$ and if all the $a_i=0$ then $d=0$

Comment: Still oustanding: can you do anything with the ratio of $B$s expression that I wrote?

Comment: $\frac2e$ is obviously true for $a_1=d=1$; not that it proves anything about other starting values, but...

Comment: @EricTowers thanks, I'll try.